# Get user object inside an entity

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, pugxmultiuserbundle

I'm trying to get user object inside an entity. I'm using FosUserBundle and PugxMultiUserBundle, and I tried the following command:

```
container->get('fos_user.user_manager')->getToken()->getUser();
```

but I get:

```
Undefined property $container
```

How can I fix it?

Thank you for your help.

The function that doesn't work is inside an entity, and it is the following:

```
protected function getUploadDir()
{
    $userManager = $this->container->get('security.context');
    $user = $userManager->findUserByUsername($this->container->get('security.context')
                ->getToken()
                ->getUser());
    return 'uploads/'.$user;
}
```

Comment: Add a $ sign at the beggining.

Comment: @Shocked I tried, and I obtain 'Undefined variable: container'

Comment: Entities don't have access to the container.  You will need to pass the user object to the entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE after @OP edited...

You cannot access the container (hence the userManager) from an entity. The entity should not access the container itself.

---

You are missing `$` before the name of your variable.

But that's not all, solution inside a controller :

```
$userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$user = $userManager->findUserByUsername($this->container->get('security.context')
                    ->getToken()
                    ->getUser())
```

But, inside a controller, your should be able to get user by doing the following :

```
$this->getUser();
```

Comment: Except he is trying to get it inside of an entity.

Comment: @Brice ok thank you, sorry for the confusion. So, If I really need to have that information inside my controller, I should do an arrayCorrelation, isn't it?

Comment: What is the entity with `protected function getUploadDir()`?

Comment: @Brice It's an entity intended to upload a file. It's quite similar the one in the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html#basic-setup)

Comment: Then I think you should add a `OneToMany` relation from `User` to `Document` in order, from `Document`, to retrieve the `User` that owns the `Document`. Or if it's not the kind of schema you want, then you should set the `path` to `Document` and use it in `getUploadDir()`.